# I want the console to log the text of an event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, mouseevent, console.log

I've made this function where what I want to have happen is that when the document registers a click event, I want the text of that event's html element to be logged to the console only if the text is "Reply". This is the code I've got at this point.

```
function clickEventText() {
        $(document).click(function (event) {
            var eventText = $(event.target).text();
            var replyText = "Reply";

            if (eventText = replyText ) {
                console.log(eventText);    
            } 

        });
    };
```

The problem I'm having is that regardless of the event.target's text the console logs the string "Reply" every time the document registers a click event.

Comment: you condition should contain `==` sign one is missing

Comment: Thanks @AswinRamesh. I've updated the code with the `==` but the result is that the console isn't logging anything when there's a click event.

Comment: give a `console.log(eventText)` above the if condition, and check whether you are getting the correct text

Comment: yup, there was lots of empty whitespace in there. All good now.

Answer (score 0):

you condition is missing `==` signs

try

```
function clickEventText() {
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        var eventText = $(event.target).text();
        var replyText = "Reply";

        if (eventText == replyText ) {
            console.log(eventText);    
        } 

    });
};
```

Comment: Obvious duplicates need comments and close-votes, not answers.